# Progress Bar on scrolling views in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am downloading some data from server and queue my tasks. When I scroll to next page I add it to queue and aslo show Progress Bar. I want that my pages still scroll either it is showing Progress Bar. I also want to change the style of Progress Bar when it is in queue and data is not started downloading yet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the indefinite progress spinner in each page. As soon as the page load completes, show the content and hide the progress spinner. Do the downloading in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Can you please tell me about "indefinite progress spinner"?

Comment: The one that goes in circle.. Set `android:indeterminate="true"` to your progress bar.

Comment: I tried with this one, but this solution not worked. I am trying to show dialog but background should not disable.

Comment: I have already mention this problem in my above question description. One problem is fixed that is different style of Progress Bar as you suggest to make it "indeterminate". Other one is I want to scroll my views if either Progress Bar is shown. Kindly help me for this.

Comment: Did yu make a asynctask for downloading? start downloading a page's content when it becomes visible first time.. how u doing this?

Comment: I start a Async Task for downloading and ThreadPoolExecutor to queue tasks.